# plotting a large dataset

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have some fairly large datasets consisting of power output data of a wind turbine over 2 years, with one value for each 10 minute period. (105500 points). When I try to plot them with matplotlib it takes very long - actually it didnt even finish so there might be some problem with my code.

I built several pd.Series out of a large dataframe. The Series are the timesteps and the power output and Im trying to simply plot them with matplotlib.

```py
    wind_avg = completeA['avg']
    wind_avg = wind_avg.dropna(how='all')
    wind_min = completeA['mini']
    wind_min = wind_min.dropna(how='all')
    power_min= completeA['min']
    power_min= power_min.dropna(how='all')
    power_avg= completeA['realo']
    power_avg=power_avg.dropna(how='all')
    zeitreihe= completeA['time']
    zeitreihe=zeitreihe.dropna(how='all')


    plt.figure(1)
    plt.plot(zeitreihe, wind_avg, label='wind_avg')
    plt.plot(zeitreihe, wind_min, label='wind_min')
    plt.plot(zeitreihe, power_min, label='power_min')
    plt.plot(zeitreihe, power_avg, label='power_avg')
    plt.ylabel('Installed capacity in MW')
    plt.xlabel('Years')
    plt.legend(loc='upper left', frameon=False)
    plt.savefig('hotzenplot.png')
    plt.show()
```

So now im sitting here and have waited for 10 minutes minimum. That cant be right, right? Do you see a problem with my code or is it actually normal to take that long? My computer is not too old.

Can I maybe compress the dataset, or just use every 10th datapoint?

Comment: Did you try either of your own suggestions?

Comment: I cut it in half, still didnt work. There is probably something inside the frame which pyplot is having problems with... Ill have another look

Comment: I still dont understand, its a simple series with values between 0 and 500. I am now down to 3000 values.

Comment: Plotting 100000 points should take up to a second roughly. A guess in the dark is that you have not converted your dates to actual dates, such that they are treated as categorical objects with each getting its own ticklabel? Because drawing 100000 individual text elements *could* take some minutes.

Comment: ohhhhhhhhh yes, that solved it, thanks!

Comment: When you really start using dataframes that are too big, you could try using `dask` (https://dask.org/) and `hvplot` (https://hvplot.pyviz.org/)